# GCP, Cloud Run static ip, is there downside?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip

I followed this example and it worked

and I`m just worried that if there is downside of it about scailing (is there any bad thing than default settings?)

simple question and I really want to know it

Comment: No real downside. Your IP can be blocked, because it's static and you use always the same. In case of large volume of outgoing traffic, only one IP will limit you, use multiple IPs in that case.

Comment: You can add/remove/change the static IP address assigned and allocated to your instance anytime!

Answer (score 1):

As per @guillaume blaquiere, there is no real downside. Your IP can be blocked, because it's static and you use always the same. In case of a large volume of outgoing traffic, only one IP will limit you, use multiple IPs in that case.